# can't get point light to light my object

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to light a simple square object with a point light , however I can't seem to render both the object and the light together. what am I doing wrong?

here is my renderer :

```
public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer  {
    private static final String TAG="TAG";
    private static final String A_COLOR = "a_Color";
    private static final String U_MATRIX = "u_Matrix";
    private static final String U_MVMATRIX = "u_MVMatrix";
    private static final String A_POSITION = "a_Position";
    private static final String A_NORMAL = "a_Normal" ;
    private static final String U_LIGHT_POS = "u_LightPos";
    private static final int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4 ;
    private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
    private static final int COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
    private static final int NORMAL_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;

    private static final int STRIDE = (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT+COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT)*BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
    private final Context context;
    private final FloatBuffer vertexData;
    private final FloatBuffer normalData;
    private int program;
    private int pointProgram ;
    private int aPositionLocation;
    private int aColorLocation;
    private int aNormalLocation;
    private int uMatrixLocation;
    private int uPointMatrixLocation;
    private int aPointPositionLocation;
    private int uMVMatrixLocation;
    private int uLightPos;
    private float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] lightModelMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mLightPosInModelSpace = new float[] {0f, 0.0f, -4.0f, 1.0f};
    private final float[] mLightPosInWorldSpace = new float[4];
    private final float[] mLightPosInEyeSpace = new float[4];
    private static final float Z_VALUE = -5.0f;

    public Renderer(Context context ) {
        this.context = context ;
        float[] table = {
                //triangle fan

                // X  ,     Y ,   Z         R  ,   G  ,   B
                   0  ,     0 ,   Z_VALUE,   1f ,   0f ,   0f ,
                -0.25f ,  -0.25f ,Z_VALUE,   1f ,   0f ,   0f ,
                 0.25f ,  -0.25f ,Z_VALUE,   1f ,   0f ,   0f ,
                 0.25f ,   0.25f ,Z_VALUE,   1f ,   0f ,   0f ,
                -0.25f ,   0.25f ,Z_VALUE,   1f   , 0f ,   0f ,
                -0.25f ,  -0.25f ,Z_VALUE,   1f   , 0f ,   0f

        };
        final float[] normal = {
                0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f ,
                0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f ,
                0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f ,
                0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f ,
                0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f ,
                0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f
        };

        vertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(table.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        vertexData.put(table);
        normalData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(normal.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        normalData.put(normal);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f,0f);

        String vertexShaderSource = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context,R.raw.simple_vertex_shader); //read simple_vertex_shader.glsl
        String fragmentShaderSource = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context, R.raw.simple_fragment_shader); //read simple_fragment_shader.glsl
        String pointVertexShader = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context , R.raw.point_vertex_shader);
        String pointFragmentShader = TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context , R.raw.point_fragment_shader) ;


        int vertexShader = ShaderHelper.compileVertexShader(vertexShaderSource); //compile the vertex shader
        int pointShaderVertex = ShaderHelper.compileVertexShader(pointVertexShader);
        int fragmentShader = ShaderHelper.compileFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSource); //compile the fragment shader
        int pointShaderFragment = ShaderHelper.compileFragmentShader(pointFragmentShader);
        program=ShaderHelper.linkProgram(vertexShader,fragmentShader); //link the shaders into a program object
            if (Logger.logging)
            ShaderHelper.validateProgram(program);



        pointProgram = ShaderHelper.linkProgram(pointShaderVertex, pointShaderFragment);
        ShaderHelper.validateProgram(pointProgram);



        aColorLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, A_COLOR); //get attribute for color
        aNormalLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program ,A_NORMAL);
        uLightPos = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, U_LIGHT_POS);
        uMVMatrixLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program , U_MVMATRIX);




        //tell openGL where to find the attribute for color
        vertexData.position(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE, vertexData);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);

        //tell openGL where to find the attribute for normal
        normalData.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aNormalLocation, NORMAL_COMPONENT_COUNT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, NORMAL_COMPONENT_COUNT * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, normalData);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aNormalLocation);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float aspect = (float)width/height;

        Matrix.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix, 0, 40, aspect, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, -2.0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        //Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewMatrix , 0 , mViewMatrix , 0 , modelMatrix , 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);
        uMatrixLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, U_MATRIX);
        aPositionLocation=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION); //get attribute for position
        //tell openGL where to find the attribute location
        vertexData.position(0);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE, vertexData);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation); //enable the vertex array



        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMVMatrixLocation, 1, false, mViewMatrix, 0);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        Matrix.setIdentityM(lightModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.translateM(lightModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);

        Matrix.multiplyMV(mLightPosInWorldSpace, 0, lightModelMatrix, 0, mLightPosInModelSpace, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMV(mLightPosInEyeSpace, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mLightPosInWorldSpace, 0);

        GLES20.glUniform3f(uLightPos, mLightPosInEyeSpace[0], mLightPosInEyeSpace[1], mLightPosInEyeSpace[2]);

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);





        GLES20.glUseProgram(pointProgram);

        uPointMatrixLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(pointProgram,U_MATRIX);
        aPointPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(pointProgram, A_POSITION); //get attribute for position

        GLES20.glVertexAttrib3f(aPointPositionLocation, mLightPosInModelSpace[0], mLightPosInModelSpace[1], mLightPosInModelSpace[2]);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(aPointPositionLocation);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, lightModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uPointMatrixLocation, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS , 0 , 1);
    }

}
```

my object vertex shader :

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;
uniform vec3 u_LightPos;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;
attribute vec3 a_Normal;



varying vec4 v_Color;


void main()
{
    vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position) ;//transform the vertex into eye space
    vec3 modelViewNormal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal,0.0)) ; //transform the normal into eye space
    float distance = length(u_LightPos - modelViewVertex) ; //will be used for attenuation
    vec3 lightVector = normalize(u_LightPos - modelViewVertex) ;
    float diffuse = max(dot(modelViewNormal,lightVector) , 0.1 );
    diffuse = diffuse * (1.0 / (1.0 + (0.25 * distance * distance)));


    v_Color=a_Color * diffuse;
    //v_Color = a_Color;
    gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position ;

}
```

my object fragment shader :

```
precision mediump float ;

varying vec4 v_Color;

void main ()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_Color ;

}
```

my point light vertex shader :

```
uniform mat4 u_Matrix;
attribute vec4 a_Position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_Matrix * a_Position ;
    gl_PointSize = 5.0;
}
```

and my point fragment shader :

```
precision mediump float;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

Edit : I can see the object now actually , but it is very VERY dim. and I changed the value of diffuse but not good.

Comment: One obvious problem is that you're creating two shader programs, but then are only using one of them in `onDrawFrame()`. There's no `glUseProgram(shader)` call in that method.

Comment: @RetoKoradi thanks for the comment. I have edited so that I have both calls to glUseProgram in the onDrawFrame . but the problem remains the same